# DateTime Joda comparison

Tags: java, datetime, comparison, jodatime

I have an list full of class objects which contains two properties: `timeStart` and `timeEnd`.

Both of them are Joda `DateTime` objects.

I am trying to get only the objects where `timeStart` is `beforeNow` && `timeEnd` is `afterNow`, as well as `timeStart` is `afterNow()` && `timeEnd` is `afterNow()`.

But seriously I am getting most of the objects, even there are not passing my condition (in theory).

I guess the problem lies at the comparison of the builtin JodaTime functions (Timezones?)

The code:

```
Main.log.info("Now: " + DateTime.now());
    for(ChannelProgramBase base : programs) {

        if(base.getTimeStart().isBeforeNow() && base.getTimeEnd().isAfterNow() || base.getTimeStart().isAfterNow() && base.getTimeEnd().isAfterNow()) {


            Main.log.info("Add: " + base.getTimeStart() + " - " + base.getTimeEnd());
            programsToPlay.add(base);
        }
    }
```

The corresponding output:

```
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.941 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 51 - Now: 2017-06-20T09:44:16.941+02:00
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.942 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T00:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T23:55:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.942 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T07:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T07:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.942 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T08:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T08:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.942 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T08:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T08:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.942 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T08:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T08:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.942 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T08:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T08:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.943 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T09:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T09:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.943 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T09:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T09:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.943 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T09:35:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T09:40:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.943 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T10:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T10:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.943 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T10:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T10:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.943 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T10:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T10:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.943 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T10:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T10:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.944 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T11:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T11:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.944 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T11:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T11:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.944 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T11:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T11:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.944 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T11:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T11:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.944 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T12:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T12:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.944 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T12:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T12:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.944 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T12:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T12:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.945 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T12:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T12:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.945 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T13:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T13:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.945 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T13:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T13:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.945 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T13:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T13:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.945 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T13:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T13:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.945 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T14:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T14:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.945 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T14:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T14:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.946 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T14:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T14:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.946 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T14:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T14:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.946 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T15:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T15:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.946 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T15:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T15:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.946 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T15:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T15:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.946 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T15:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T15:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.946 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T16:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T16:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.947 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T16:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T16:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.947 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T16:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T16:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.947 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T16:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T16:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.947 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T17:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T17:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.947 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T17:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T17:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.947 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T17:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T17:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.948 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T17:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T17:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.948 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T18:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T18:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.948 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T18:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T18:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.948 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T18:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T18:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.948 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T18:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T18:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.948 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T19:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T19:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.948 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T19:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T19:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.948 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T19:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T19:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.949 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T19:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T19:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.949 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T20:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T20:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.949 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T20:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T20:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.949 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T20:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T20:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.949 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T20:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T20:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.949 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T21:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T21:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.949 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T21:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T21:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.950 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T21:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T21:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.950 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T21:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T21:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.950 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T22:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T22:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.950 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T22:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T22:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.950 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T22:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T22:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.950 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T22:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T22:50:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.950 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T23:00:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T23:05:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.950 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T23:15:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T23:20:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.951 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T23:30:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T23:35:00.000Z
[INFO ] 2017-06-20 09:44:16.951 [PlayerHandler-Thread]  line 57 - Add: 2017-06-20T23:45:00.000Z - 2017-06-20T23:50:00.000Z
```

Comment: It's not clear to me, in what cases your code is failing when it shouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
Main.log.info("Now: " + DateTime.now());
    for(ChannelProgramBase base : programs) {

        if((base.getTimeStart().isBeforeNow() && base.getTimeEnd().isAfterNow()) || (base.getTimeStart().isAfterNow() && base.getTimeEnd().isAfterNow())) {


            Main.log.info("Add: " + base.getTimeStart() + " - " + base.getTimeEnd());
            programsToPlay.add(base);
        }
    }
```

Comment: well, really embarrassed now, of forgetting brackets in an combined condition :)

but there is an similar output now: https://pastebin.com/ZmM8pGck
If i substract the +02:00 which occurs at the end of my "now-string" the output would be correct. Any guesses?